# Can't run QubitSpectroscopy from qiskit experiments library

Tags: qiskit

So this question inherits from my [previous problem](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/trying-to-run-qubit-spectroscopy-on-fakemanila-backend-got-unknown-instruction) , but owing to its perceptible distinction, I decided to write it separately. Long story short, I want to construct a Qubit Spectroscopy experiment using qiskit and IBM backends.

First of all I write my script based on [this tutorial](https://learn.qiskit.org/course/quantum-hardware-pulses/calibrating-qubits-using-qiskit-pulse) and source code of [`qiskit_experiments.library.QubitSpectroscopy`](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/experiments/stubs/qiskit_experiments.library.characterization.QubitSpectroscopy.html#qiskit_experiments.library.characterization.QubitSpectroscopy). [Script is here](https://gist.github.com/ikaryss/51bb98213530410226dc47761bbee230). Job was launched but failed with code 7001: `Instruction Spec is not supported`.

Secondly I tried to run such experiment on some fake backend in order to debug all possible errors. This is where I decided to write my previous question. Thankfully, [Yael Ben-Haim gave me some hint](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/33949/26023) to use Dynamics Backend but unfortunately I was faced with `Operation 'Spec_gate' on qubit(s) [0] not supported by the backend` error again. [Here is my dynamic backend script](https://gist.github.com/ikaryss/7d1cf31d6f25a067ca86bf589ab37163).

Lastly, I decided to simply use [`qiskit_experiments.library.QubitSpectroscopy`](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/experiments/stubs/qiskit_experiments.library.characterization.QubitSpectroscopy.html#qiskit_experiments.library.characterization.QubitSpectroscopy) with *ibm_nairobi* backend. [Here is my qiskit-experiments script](https://gist.github.com/ikaryss/1419f3ac20047b8dc8e1a82134a3f075). I thought that in this simpler way I can tackle some problems regarding my insufficient qiskit experience, but it didn't work either, the job was crashed with error message: `Error code 8019; For channel d1, Final channel time exceeds max time (2448000000000 > 4194304)`. Furthermore, when I tried delve deeper in [error 8019](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/ibm-runtime/errors.html#id6:%7E:text=Reduce%20the%20total%20length%20of%20pulse%20sequence%20on%20the%20specified%20channel.) and figure out why my pulse schedules are so long, I've faced with `operation not supported` error once again (details in my last script)

To conclude:
So I really want to figure out where am I wrong and how can I handle these problems in order to run my calibration experiments on real devices. I'd love to hear some hints!

Comment: For the second question, my colleague Naoki Kanazawa says to provide instructions in SI instead of dt.